# Why don't we consider stack frame sizes while calculation Space Complexity of recursive procedures?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, space-complexity

Consider, the case of `Merge Sort` on an `int Array` containing `n` elements, we need an additional array of size `n` in order to perform merges.We discard the additional array in the end though.So the space complexity of Merge Sort comes out to be `O(n)`.
But if you look at the recursive `mergeSort` procedure, on every recursive call `mergeSort(something)` one stack frame is added to the stack.And it does take some space, right?

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] a,int low,int high)
{
    if(low<high)
    {
        int mid=(low+high)/2;
        mergeSort(a,low,mid);
        mergeSort(a,mid+1,high);
        merge(a,mid,low,high);
    }
}
```

**My Questions is :**

1. Why don't we take the size of stack frames into consideration while
   calculating Merge Sort complexity ?
2. Is it because the stack contains only a few integer variables and
   one reference, which don't take much memory?
3. What if my recursive function creates a new local array(lets say `int a[]=new int [n];`).Then will it be considered in calculating Space complexity?

Comment: 2. is the correct answer to 1. As for 3, *yes*.

Comment: Note that the array will not on be on the stack in Java. Only the reference to the array will be.

Comment: True ! There will just be a reference on stack in JAVA. Does the size of that reference should be considered in space complexity?

Comment: the size of reference is O(1); the number of stack frames = recursion depth, is logarithmic, O(log n), for mergesort. This will only be important if you manage to make `merge` to be O(1) in space (i.e. merge in-place). Then yes, instead of O(1) algorithm you'll have O(log n) algorithm, space-wise.

Comment: @WillNess You are right, but as specified in the answer, all the stack frames don't live on stack at the same time. They keep decreasing and increasing during the execution of program.

Comment: @AmanArora right, that's why there aren't O(n) of them, but there are O(logn) of them at one time, when the bottom is reached.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, so the ideal space complexity is `O(n+logn)` but it evaluates `O(n)`.

Comment: @AmanArora correct, *if* your space requirement is otherwise O(n); and that it will be if you use copy-array to merge the two parts. But, if you manage to merge them *in-place*, in O(1) space, *then* the O(log n) part becomes significant. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space consumed by the stack should absolutely be taken into consideration, but some may disagree here (I believe some algorithms even make complexity claims ignoring this - there's an unanswered related question about radix sort floating around here somewhere).

Since we split the array in half at each recursive call, the size of the stack will be `O(log n)`.

So, if we take it into consideration, the total space will be `O(n + log n)`, which is just `O(n)` (because, in big-O notation, we can discard asymptotically smaller terms), so it doesn't change the complexity.

And for creating a local array, a similar argument applies. If you create a local array at each step, you end up with `O(n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ...) = O(2n) = O(n)` (because, in big-O notation, we can discard constant factors), so that doesn't change the complexity either.

Comment: There will be `n` recursive calls to `mergeSort()` and the size of each stack frame will be same, isn't it?

Comment: @AmanArora The size of each stack frame will be the same, and there will be `O(n)` recursive calls, but they won't all be on the stack at once - picture a binary tree where the root is size `n`, and each child is half the size of the parent - while the entire tree may have `O(n)` nodes, if you iterate through this tree, you'll only go as deep as the maximum depth of the tree, which is `O(log n)` - once you return from any node, it's no longer on the stack.

Comment: So what i have concluded is "We should take stack frame sizes into consideration ?"

Comment: @AmanArora That's perfect. But, if for the purposes of a class, you should perhaps just ask your lecturer what he/she thinks, and go with that, to prevent possible disagreements / lose of marks in future.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not calculating the space-complexity when you are doing that. That is called determining: you are doing tests and try to conclude what the space complexity is by looking at the results. This is not a mathematical approach.

And yes, you are right with statement 2.

Comment: Right! But why aren't we considering the sizes of stack in those tests?

Comment: If you want to determine the space complexity instead of calculate it, you could take the stack size into account.